# PHPUnit merged coverage reports not showing method opening brace as covered

Tags: php, phpunit

OK, heres the scenario.

We have 2 separate Zend projects that share some common code. The common code contains abstract classes and controllers that are extended in each project.

At the moment the common code is sym-linked into each project.

We have unit tests in each project that cover some of the abstract classes from the common code.

I have configured phpunit so that it includes the common code from it's normal place on disk (rather than the sym-linked location).

I generate the coverage files using --coverage-php and then merge them using phpcov.

The report shows both projects and the common code, however, in many of the common classes, the opening curly brace of each method is showing as executable code without coverage. So our reports are lower than they should be.

I have attached an example image of the HTML report.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: After a little more digging, even without merging the reports the common code shows the opening braces of methods as executable code without coverage.

ANOTHER EDIT: I think I have found the reason (But not the solution).
In a class that is included in the test suite, but not covered under unit tests, ALL method lines (including opening braces) are marked as executed but not covered.

So in my coverage reports, the common unit test report has an array entry for row 35 for the file in the image, but the other projects don't have this entry. After the merge, the other lines are being marked as covered but this one isn't. So the problem is that uncovered files, show the opening curly brace as an uncovered line, rather than dead code.

Comment: I believe this has something to do with an issue in XDebug and the parsing of statements.  You need to have the brace on a line by itself, and not with the function declaration for XDebug to properly parse it.  I believe if you continue to look with the XDebug referenced as well, you will find a technical parsing reason with XDebug, PHP and the opcode.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem merging two reports using `phpcov` as you've described. I also got the issue where some lines such as opening braces in files which were covered by one test suite, but that were not covered in another were showing as uncovered executable lines.

To get the the merged report to show correctly the `addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist` and `processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist` options need to be set correctly (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29042391/2220615 contains good explanations).

The default for `addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist` is `TRUE`, so all files in the whitelist will be added to the report, but `processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist` defaults to `FALSE`, so every line in s file which isn't covered in a particular suite is marked as executable and uncovered.

To fix, I set `processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist` to `TRUE` for both coverage reports, then the merged report, correctly shows the lines as dead code instead of uncovered.